# Use different keyboard for a file

Tags: bash, keyboard

I want to set the keyboard to Spanish using `setxkbmap es`, as long as I have opened a certain .txt file using mousepad (if the keyboard could be Spanish only for that file it would be even better) for an example. Say I use an alias `mpes` which opens the file and sets the keyboard to Spanish.

Is there a way to script this, such that when the file gets closed the keyboard returns automatically to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
function mpes { setxkbmap es; gedit viva_espagna.txt; setxkbmap en; }
```

It set keyboard to `ES`, open `viva_espagna.txt` and then set the keyboard to `EN` (when the previous has returned (eg you closed the editor)

You can add this to your `~/.bashrc` file to make it permanent when you open a new terminal (`source ~/.bashrc`)

Comment: Is there a way to restrict the Spanish keyboard to the one texteditor but use an internet explorer with an English at the same time?

Comment: Also can I make sure the regular gedit opens the file (and only that one) in this fashion?

Comment: Use a function instead: `mpes () { setxkbmap es; gedit viva_espagna.txt; setxkbmap en; }`.

Comment: you want to use ES in your opened file editor & EN in your browser at the same time is that right ?  I dont think it is possible but maybe your browser may have some options for keyboard language settings

Comment: @chepner thanks a function would fit better for this